# jQuery, use event.target inside .on()

Tags: jquery

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function preview(obj){
  ...
}
```

and here is how I call the function,

```
$('.parent').on('click','.child',preview);
```

The problem is how to I define the "obj",
I tried the following code, but no luck.

```
$('.parent').on('click','.child',{obj:event.target},preview);
```

Or the only way I can use is like this, which I tried and work as expected.

```
$('.parent').on('click','.child',function(){
  preview($(this));
});
```

Comment: You should still have access to `this` inside that defined handler without passing anything in.... `event` gets passed in by default. http://jsfiddle.net/aL7hzs4d/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$('.parent').on('click','.child',function(event){
  preview(event.target);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but answer from tymeJV looks like more conveniences to me. :)